# Is there a way for the Redux Debugger plugin in Flipper to always select the most recent action in the log?

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, flipper

I've recently set up the Redux Debugger plugin in Flipper and I'm using it with an Expo-managed React Native app. Does anyone know if there's a way to have the list of redux actions in the main pane always select the most recent action? This would allow the state pane to show the state updating in realtime, which is very useful in other redux debuggers that have that ability. Thanks in advance.